# mySql or sql c# deployment origanaly acsess small database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Using c#
I have a small database that I have created I used access now I wish to port it to SQL or SQL server. In deployment which is easiest. With access you have to bundle the assess driver, do you have to bundle anything when using mysql or sql?

Comment: In general, you have to bundle the SQL server software and licensing. Perhaps consider SQLite?

Comment: SQLite is that easyier@NetMAge

Comment: Can you explain what is the relevance of the _xml-parsing_ tag in this question? Do not misuse tags.

Comment: If each installation has its own database then definitely SQLite, there is no runtime, just dlls.

Comment: @steve the source for the tables will come from xml No it was not a trick question